# Django/Python: How to pass a variable from a form to a python script with POST method?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm getting this error when  submit:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

I've got this far following the documentation, but I don't fully understand it and it's definitely wrong. I just want to take a query word from my search box(form) and pass it to a python script as an argument. I'm new to Django and getting stuck on the easiest things.

In models.py:

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label='query',max_length=100)
```

I added this line to my urls.py

```
url(r'^results/$', 'tweemo.views.results'),
```

On my homepage where my search box is I have this code for my form:

```
<form action="/home/results/" method="post">
    <label for="query">Search:</label>
    <input id="query" type="text" name="query" value="{{ current_query }}">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

In views.py I added these two functions:

```
def get_query(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.isvalid():
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
         form = QueryForm()
    return render(request, 'results.html', {'form': form})

def results(request):
    return render_to_response('results.html',{'here':TwitterStream.objects.all() })
```

MY results.html contains just this:

```
<form action="/home/results/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You need a `{% csrf_token %}` like this...  `<form ...>{% csrf_token %}` Another thing - It is not a good idea to serve `/search` requests as a `POST`. The reason being the use can bookmark the link, etc.. if it is a GET request (ease of use.)

Answer (score 2):

You must just add the `{% csrf_token %}` tag inside **EVERY** `<form></form>` tag which has method to be `post` in your template.

So the below markup should be corrected:

```
<form action="/home/results/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="query">Search:</label>
    <input id="query" type="text" name="query" value="{{ current_query }}">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks,but that didn't fix it actually.

Comment: So, I want to ask, which page and which form did you submit from that leads to the error? What's the `method` attribute of that form? The `CSRF verification` error only occurs when the form was submitted with `post` method and doesn't have the 'csrf_token' field. @COOLBEANS

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that you are not passing the csrf token to the form , you need to pass the csrf token to the render function in order for it to be applied in the form . To accomplish this you need to associate the csrf token to the request.

```
def get_query(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.isvalid():
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
         form = QueryForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('results.html', args)

def results(request):
    return render_to_response('results.html',{'here':TwitterStream.objects.all() })
```